# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost

Tags: symfony

I have an problem width production in my page web I imported my project in my server and I done my cache in active access but my site is inactive my error is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)' in
>   /home/sbstn/public_html/convention/CoCoSecto/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43

my parameter to connection :

```
parameters:
    database_host: Localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: sbctn_convention
    database_user: sbctn
    database_password:**********
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: bde5720b4958a77108513d0e7ffe4662e8ad00f3
```

Please suggest me for better solution .

Answer (score 1):

2 things to do:

- Check your database parameters defined in `app/config_prod.yml`
- Clear your production cache: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`